# Best URL Shortening Algorithm

Tags: url, url-shortener

I was wondering what is the best algorithm for URL shortening.  I noticed most people do the following:

1) Get Unique auto generated id from database.
2) Encode unique auto generated id to Base 64 value.

Its kind of obvious to a user what previous url's might be.  What can I do to make it harder for the user to figure out what algorithm I'm using?

Thank you,
Tesh

Comment: How do you think it will be obvious for user what previous URI might be? And all the URI are in-fact going to open up the web address they belong to. So I am not able to get the use case or the reason why you are trying to hide the algorithm. Even if user predicted it, then what? OR is it just a programming exercise where you want to generate a short unique string and associate it with some URI?

Answer (score 2):

Generate an id at random and check to see if it has been used already?

Comment: What if two people get the same random number at the same time?  How do I account for that?  That is why I was using the auto generated id after inserting a value into a table.  I'm using mysql.  Do I have to do some type of locking of the table and see if it exists.  If it exists, try another random number?

Comment: After generating check whether the number already exists. If not regenerate. If there are too many regeneration. U need to increase the bucket size

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use a SHA to hash it

EDIT: Better generate a random number and hash it as Jon pointed out

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not a good idea to put authentication information (*e.g.* usernames and passwords) in URLs (users would reveal their passwords simply by copy/pasting links, *etc.*).

That said, if you want to obscure the order that URLs were added to the shortening service, you could use the output of a cryptographic hash function such as MD5 or SHA1 (which is considered "irreversible", *i.e.* infeasible to derive the input from the output), base-64 encode that, and take eight characters, for example. The input to the hash function could be the URL (possibly the current time as well).

Comment: I tried your idea where I md5 my auto generated integer id. Then I encoded 64.  I get a long string YzRjYTQyMzhhMGI5MjM4MjBkY2M1MDlhNmY3NTg0OW.  Are you saying I take the first 8 characters of this?  If I do then I would have to make sure those first 8 don't already exists for previous urls right?